# MySQL: get current and next record based on date

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
+----+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+
| id |   name    | date_start |  date_end  | is_active |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+
| 12 | Invernale | 2016-11-01 | 2017-03-31 |         1 |
| 15 | Estivo    | 2016-09-01 | 2016-09-01 |         1 |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

I need to get the "current" record based on today and next record, today based.

In my example, "current" is id 15 and "next" will be 12.

Today, same query will return "NULL" (or no record) for the current and 15 for next.

On the November, 01st 2016, current will be 12 and next no record.

On the April, 01st 2017 both will need return no record.

These are my query, but both will return id 15 (at today).

```
$sql_current = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE date_start <= '$now' AND date_end >= '$now'";

$sql_next = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE date_start >= '$now' ORDER BY date_start ASC LIMIT 1";
```

Thank you very much

Comment: **In my example, "current" is id 15 and "next" will be 15.** is it correct? the third line.

Comment: @1000111 no, it was an error. Just edited. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can get those two records (if any) in a single query with the help of `UNION` (if I didn't misunderstand)

```
(
    SELECT 
    *
    FROM tableName 
    WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN date_start AND date_end
    LIMIT 1 
)
UNION 
(
    SELECT 
    *
    FROM tableName
    WHERE date_start > CURDATE() 
    ORDER BY date_start 
    LIMIT 1
);
```

**EDIT:**

If you would like to know which entry is `current` and which one is `next` then you can add an extra column `currentOrNext` like below:

```
(
    SELECT 
    *,
    'current' AS currentOrNext
    FROM tableName 
    WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN date_start AND date_end
    LIMIT 1 
)
UNION 
(
    SELECT 
    *,
    'next' AS currentOrNext
    FROM tableName
    WHERE date_start > CURDATE() 
    ORDER BY date_start 
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you need to get the interval that contains the current date (`CURDATE() BETWEEN date_start AND date_end`) and the first interval that is in the future and doesn't contain the current date.

The following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE CURDATE() <= date_end
ORDER BY date_end ASC
LIMIT 2
```

produces the first two time intervals (or less) that are not in the past (termination date is in the future).

A couple of lines of code in client code (PHP probably) can check the value of `start_date` of the first returned row (if any) to decide if it can be used as "current" or "next":

- if no rows are returned then `current` is `NULL` and `next` is `NULL`;
- else if `start_date` of the first returned row is in the past then `current` is the first returned row and `next` is the second returned row`(if any) or`NULL` (only one row was returned by the query);
- else `current` is `NULL`, `next` is the first row and the second row (if any) is not needed.